# Trigger a click event into a click handler on links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a link like this :

```
 <a id="downloadReport" href="">Download</a>
```

What I would like to do is to when the link is clicked is to update the href attribute of the element through an AJAX request and then trigger the click event to follow the link. Here's the Javascript code:

```
$("#downloadReport").click(function(event)
{
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    if ($(this).attr('href') == "")
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var year = parseInt($("#reportYears").val());

        if (year != 0)
        {
            $.post(
                "/Trainings/getReport",
                {data: year},
                function(data)
                {
                    $("#downloadReport").attr('href', data.trim());
                    $("#downloadReport").click();
                });
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

So normally the behaviour should be:

1. Link is clicked
2. href is printed
3. href is null -> enter if
4. default click event is prevented
5. AJAX request
6. href is updated
7. click event is triggered
8. href is printed
9. href is not null
10. return true -> link should be followed

I'm getting a null string then a valid link in the outup, so the AJAX request and the click event trigger worked, but the link is not followed on the second event.
Shouldn't the default event be triggered if true is returned ?

Comment: just use `window.location` to change, why does it need to be done through the DOM?

Comment: Why do you have to retrigger the click event? You can simple do a `window.location`.

Comment: I didn't want to do a window.location because I wanted to keep the current window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#downloadReport").click();` will trigger the jquery handler attached to it. You need to use dom click event inorder to redirect to the new href. Use like this

```
$("#downloadReport")[0].click();
```